# Google Analytics Domain Tracking API _link() method

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Has anyone else had any problems using google's Domain Tracking API, I am specifically talking about the _link() method.

[The documentation is here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._link)

The example provided shows that the _link() method should be used in the onclick event like this:

```
<a href="http://www.newsite.com" onclick="pageTracker._link('http://www.newsite.com');return false;">Go to our sister site</a>
```

However, this essentially just makes the link...do nothing (most probably because of the 'return false').

My understanding is that the pageTracker._link() method is 'supposed' to add additional parameters to the url and do it's own document.location style redirect.

Any ideas / catches / previous posts??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently a miss-interpretation of the documentation:

> You must **also** enable linking on the target site

So lets clarify **also**

- pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true); is set on the ORIGINATING page
- pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true); is set on the TARGET page

I only had it enabled on the target page, as the docs indicate.

Comment: If anyone is still listening to this really old thread... what about from the linking from the targeted page back to the originating page.  From the documentation here: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#multipleDomains it doesn't really say (or not clearly enough that I'm confident).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the obvious question, but did you enable linking on the target page:

> You must also enable linking on the target site (`pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);`) in order for link to work properly.